# Javascript compare strings returned from prompt

Tags: javascript, html, string, compare, prompt

Hi I am new to javascript and I have been trying for an hour but I honestly have no clue why this isn't working. I went on sites searching and it looks like it should work. I am checking if the answer returned by the prompt stored in x is equal to "Al Bundy". I printed out the x value and I know it returns the value the user typed in but I have had no luck with this compare.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var x;
            var check;

            function Question()
            {
                x = window.prompt("In the hit show Married with Children who scored 4 touchdowns in 1 game at polk high?");

            if(x == 'Al Bundy')
            {
                windows.confirm("You are CORRECT!\n\nNow Just confirm to be redirected to our agents.");
            }
            else
            {
                windows.confirm("Sorry that is not correct...no money for you.");
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "Question()">

        <script>
            window.alert("You have been selected to answer a question for\n\n50 MILLION DOLLARS");
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for help. I know my rating will probably drop but I searched and honestly I have no clue why this does not work. I have tried many different things.

Comment: You have a typo, `windows.confirm` instead `window.confirm` (or just `confirm`). Fix it and try then

Answer (score 1):

your mistake is in this line:

```
windows.confirm("Sorry that is not correct...no money for you.");
```

and

```
windows.confirm("You are CORRECT...
```

please change 'windows.confirm' to 'window.confirm'.

Comment: That's very depressing. Thank you. Sorry for that.